# Is there a colorblind friendly alternative to the tab colormaps?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, colormap, color-blindness

I am currently preparing matplotlib plots for publication and they have to be colorblind friendly. It seems as if the tab colormaps in matplotlib (I'm specifically using the tab20b colormap) aren't colorblind friendly.

Is there are similarly 'tabbed' colormap that is suitable for colorblindess?

Comment: See https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html#color-vision-deficiencies  you can avoid colormaps containing both green and red.

Comment: colorcet (https://colorcet.holoviz.org/) and seaborn (https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html) both have alternative options